# Best Practise for Document Parser

Tags: spring-boot, rest, design-patterns, coding-style, pdf-generation

Everyone
I need one help for building application as Document Parser. What am I doing is to convert docx to pdf in spring boot and sending file over REST channel.
But I have doubt that is it a good practise of sending file or we should convert the file first save it somewhere in server like amazon and then send the download link to user to download.
Because in my spring boot application too it is also saving the file and sending it.
I don't know the right procedure.
Any suggestions would be a great help, that how to deal with this problem.

Comment: Hello, even if you use an external server to store your file, you will need to send the file via the network. i dont see any bad practice in using a REST controller to post the file to your server and then do the conversion in the server. these docs might help : https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/  and this one https://www.baeldung.com/pdf-conversions-java

Comment: @CheikhHAIBALA, Thanks for reply. I found this in article,-
In a production scenario, you more likely would store the files in a temporary location, a database, or perhaps a NoSQL store (such as Mongo’s GridFS). It is best to NOT load up the file system of your application with content.


It means that we should have a database to store our files and then we can serve the user to download the file from database. This means we can store the files in database and then can give the file from database. 
Am I right?

But what if file is too large to store?

Comment: What is good practice or not also depends on the expected throughput (average/peak), expected document sizes (average, peak), time you guarantee the item remains available, resources of server, ... It of course makes sense to implement one's service so it is easily extendable to use external storage, but it does not need to do so from the start, in particular if your starting workload only is, say, 10 conversions of no-frills single-page documents per hour.